# Flask generate 404 page if data not found in database

Tags: python, flask

I have a method that looks a bit like this:

```py
@app.route("/cms/<path:path>")
def show_page(path):
     page = db.page.get(path=path)
     if page is None:
          return "Page not found", 404
     return str(page)
```

However, I would like to show my applications default 404 page instead of just this string.

The error should be indistinguishable from a real 404. I don't want to render any specific template, but rather whatever one is rendered for a standard 404.

Is there a way to manually render an error page? I can't seem to find the right search terms.

Comment: Do you have an `html` file/page that you want to return?

Comment: No, I want to return the 404 page

Comment: You should create a method `not_found` that return not found page as follows: `return render_template("404.html")` and replace your `return "Page not found", 404` with `return redirect(url_for("not_found")) `

Comment: No, I don't want to render a template. I want to render the default 404 page

Comment: I'm confused; where is that default 404 page?

Comment: Are you looking for `abort(404)`?

Comment: This is for a module, not a main application. I don't know what the main app has set their 404 page to, if anything. What is most important is that it should be indistinguishable from a real 404.

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/?highlight=404#custom-error-pages), there're only 3 major ways to handle 404 errors:

1. Using the `render_template` (must have `404.html`).

Example:

```py
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    # note that we set the 404 status explicitly
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

2. Using `render_template_string` (write HTML template inside your code).

Example:

```py
from flask import render_template_string
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    # note that we set the 404 status explicitly
    return render_template_string('PageNotFound {{ errorCode }}', errorCode='404'), 404
```

3. Using `abort`:
   Refer to [the docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.abort)

```py
abort(404)  # 404 Not Found
abort(Response('Hello World'))
```